# In French, can you say « tenez-vous bien » before a punchline to pique the listener's interest?

Tags: expressions

> ***Figurez-vous qu***'on vient de recevoir un email d'Alyssa nous annonçant, ***tenez-vous bien***, qu’elle aurait à son tour repéré un OVNI !

In order to express the idea of "guess what" and whatnot, I usually use the locution « *figurez-vous que ...* » at the beginning of a sentence. But what about when you want to express this idea in the middle of a sentence?

I wonder if you can place the locution « *tenez-vous bien* » or « *tiens-toi bien* » right before what you consider an interesting piece of information to spark the listener's interest in what's to come?

Incidentally, I assume you cannot start off a sentence with « *tenez-vous que ...* » in the same vein as « *figurez-vous que ...* ». Likewise, you cannot insert « *figurez-vous bien* » halfway through in place of « *tenez-vous bien* », I suppose?

Comment: You are translating: Get ready to [whatever], right? The best way to say that is merely: Attention ! [Then you say your piece]. Guess what is: Tu sais quoi? Figurez-vous is not guess what. Tenez-vous bien sounds like earth-shattering news is about to be delivered....

Comment: Figurez-vous is more like: And you know [blah blah blah].

Comment: Or "wait for it!" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of way to mark a point of interest, you can almost litterally use guess what with  « vous ne devinerez jamais », or for a really casual locution to one person « devine quoi, ... ». You can also use « saviez vous que ».

As for « tenez-vous que ... » and « figurez-vous bien » are not correct expression, « tenez-vous bien » can be translated as "hold yourself tight" and « tenez-vous que ... » would have no meaning for French people.

However, yes you can use « tenez-vous bien » or « tiens-toi bien » right before a point of interest like you do in your example, but i am not quite sure what is your question.

I hope my English isn't too bad and i have been of some help.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm a french citizen)

Yes, you can say :

> On vient de recevoir un email d'Alyssa nous annonçant, **tenez-vous bien**, qu’elle aurait à son tour repéré un OVNI !

I think the begining of the sentence is a synonym of

> Vous vous rendez compte, on vient de...

"Figurez-vous" and "tenez-vous bien" are two different expressions to express the need of attention from the interlocutor

But

> Tenez-vous que

is not a correct. It means nothing.

PS : If you need more explaination, ask in comment, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hi. Am I correct in assuming that you cannot leave out "bien" in "tenez-vous bien"?

Comment: @Alone-zee You can't, it's a set phrase with *bien*.

Comment: @Laure Hi. Does this locution basically want to say: "Tenez-vous **prêts** à être étonnés"?

Comment: @Alone-zee No, the litteral meaning is "Hold on to something", in the same way that you could say "You might want to sit down for this" - meaning you could be so shocked by the following statement that you would fall. (But "tenez-vous bien" is just for surprising statements, not negative statements).

Comment: @Alone-zee Tenez-vous bien is an attempt at translating: Get ready [for this], etc. Right??

Comment: @Alone-zee I think you CAN use just "Tenez vous" without "bien" but it's more familiar, it's a shortcut. Yes, you can translate this by "Get ready (for this)" or "Heads up".

Answer (score 0):

When someone is about to announce some dramatic news, it's not unheard of to request their counterpart to take a sit:

> Assieds toi, s'il te plait. J'ai une nouvelle importante à t'apprendre.

The purpose is to avoid the counterpart to be hurt, if he or she come to faint when discovering this announcement.